# Putting a logged in user's credit card number in hidden field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, model-binding

User has to log in to view their credit card information.  I was wondering if it's safe at that point to put that number in a hidden-field.  The reason I have to do that is because of MVC's model binding.  If that field is not there then I loose the credit-card number and will have to make additional web-service calls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to wander over to [Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions) and ask about this stuff there. You'll get much more in depth answers.

Comment: Welcome to 1998! (oh yeah, and probably PCI penalties too. In short, just don't do this.)

Comment: Erm... you're spitting the consumer's credit card number (PAN) back out at them, in full? This is a really bad idea - usual practice is to show only the final four digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not safe.because anybody can edit it and submit.You can keep it in a session.

It is easy for a malicious user to see and modify the contents of a hidden field. Do not store any information in a hidden field that is sensitive or that your application relies on to work properly.from MSDN

All session management methods are here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 11):

Even keeping that in session is NOT secure. Move your back side and do it properly.

Remember - anything that stores and processes credit card information falls under PCI-DSS regulations and if you do it this way (hidden field), your product will get thrown out of the door on the first check, hopefully before it creates extra legal + financial liability to the company using it.

Comment: I hit the upvote button on this so hard, I think it broke my mouse.

Comment: This is an old post, but a link for a demo on what you are proposing would be much more helpful than saying "do it properly".